# If $n\rightarrow \infty, h_n\rightarrow 0$ and $n h_n\rightarrow 0$, then $n=o(1/h)$.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, self-learning

This is the basic question:
If $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $ h_n\rightarrow 0$ but I want that $n h_n\rightarrow 0$, then I must impose $n=o(1/h_n)$? See [little-oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) notation.

Since I want that $nh_n=o(1)$, then $n$ satisfies $n=1/h_n o(1)=o(1/h_n)$. 
Is this right?

Comment: U need to impose $h_n=o(n^{-1})$.